# EditText boxes do not scale on small screens

Tags: android

I have a problem i cant resolve with EditText boxes in my views.
If i preview any of my views in eclipse, the EditText boxes look fine in small and larger screens, and appear to scale as expected. But in small screens they appear larger in height on the screen. They appear to scale on the width ok, but grow in height, leaving more margin between the text and the border.

The xml is very small:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/width" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:hint="Slab Width (mm)" 
android:inputType="phone"
>
</EditText>
```

I would have expected the box to be scaled in height to suit the screen.
I am surprised it does not scale in height.
I am shocked it gets larger in physical height...????

Small screen: http://www.doobox.co.uk/rapidimages/smallscreen.png

edit: Its actually QVGA & WQVGA screens that have this problem..!

I think your going to need full xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget36"
android:background="@drawable/linen_bg"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/main_linear"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" android:layout_marginRight="20dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/logo"
android:background="@drawable/conc_logo"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
>
</ImageView>
<TextView android:text="Slab Calculator" 
android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textSize="20sp" 
android:textColor="#333333" 
android:layout_marginTop="20dip">
</TextView>



<EditText android:id="@+id/length" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:inputType="phone" 
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
android:hint="Height of Slab (mm)" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>



<TextView android:text="**.** Cubic Meter's" 
android:id="@+id/slab_result" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20sp" 
android:textColor="#333333" 
android:layout_marginTop="5dip">
</TextView>

<TextView android:text="£**.** Total" 
android:id="@+id/slab_cost" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20sp" 
android:textColor="#333333" 
android:layout_marginTop="5dip">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="20dip"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/calculate_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/calculate" 
android:text="Calculate" 
android:background="@android:color/transparent">
</Button>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You'll have to be more precise. What sizes? And most importantly what are the densities of the screens you tested on?

Comment: I just added full xml to the post..!

Comment: It's strange for me, why it will be scaled though you use for height wrap_content

Comment: What i think could be happening here is: the linear layout is stretching in height, and stretching the contents. If i am correct, how..? as it is set to wrap content..?

Comment: I think, we had the same problem, because small screens will be support first from Android 1.6. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, may be your problem is in your Manifest.

Support for all screens should be declared there

```
<supports-screens
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:smallScreens="true"
   android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Another thing, SDK Api 4 should be declared in your Manifest as well. Small screens will be supported first from 1.6

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>
```

Hope, I'm not so wrong

Comment: i added this to the manifest, with no joy.. What i have just concluded with a test is: i created a new project android 1.6, api4, then added one editText area to the layout.. works fine..! so the problem i am having is probably not with my xml.. its more likely in the manifest or the activity..

Comment: i would also say, your xml is correct. Have you tried to change target sdk of your project to 1.6? Or even to 2.2?

Comment: I think i have found the problem, with the help of your answer, i have built the project, with the target 2.1 api level 7... adding the min sdk and the target sdk to the manifest at this stage does  not solve the problem. just creates an error in the manifest. versions dont match..!

Comment: >just creates an error in the manifest. versions dont match..!> Strange. My projects have in manifest minSDK=3, targetSdk=4, and build target of my project is 8, and I don't get any errors

Comment: to be more precise its a warning: "attribute min sdk version(4) is lower than the project target api level 7"

Comment: Yep... just created a test project in eclipse with: target 2.1 and min sdk 4.. and it generates this same warning, also the origonal problem in this post exists in the new test project.... so it seems to me that its the build target that does not support the low resolutions..? and setting the minimum target after that does not resolve this...

Comment: Just for reference target android 2.1 recomends sdk level 7.

Comment: So i guess my new question is: with a build target of 7 "android 2.1".. and min sdk level 7... can small screens/ low resolution screens be supported...?

Comment: Do you know what it is thats the problem here...."Eclipse"..!   I just tested the problem screen in a qvga small screen emulator and it looks fine... in eclipse xml layout it looks like it has the problem described.. still dont know why, but the good news is it looks fine in the real application.

Comment: I wrote it already, that small screens will be supported from 1.6+. You've seen it as well, as you created a project for api=4. So it should work for api level 7. Can't you try it with a device (or how had you tested it before)?

Comment: Yes, Eclipse shows layouts sometimes in a strange way. It's always better to test it on device :)

Comment: Lesson learned...! thank you all for your patience.. i only have a galaxy s as an actual physical device for testing. but the emulators i have built should do the trick for small screens now.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly specifying `android:padding` for your `EditText` and see if that might help.